# Alternatives to arc

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-arrows

For reference, I am trying to re-create this diagram from a 1931 paper.

[image: Diagram]
After looking [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95936/create-curved-tikz-single-arrow?noredirect=1&lq=1), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76073/repositioning-and-resizing-arrow-tip-on-circular-arc-path), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/449008/arrowhead-angle-in-tikz?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175016/how-is-arc-defined-in-tikz) I managed to generate the following:

[image: Current Output]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{circlelined} = [circle, minimum width=6em, text centered, draw=black, ultra thick]
\tikzstyle{circledashed} = [dashedlong, circle, minimum width = 6em, text centered, draw=black, thick]
\tikzstyle{circleblank} = [circle, minimum width=6em]
\tikzstyle{dashedlong}=                  [dash pattern=on 22pt off 4pt]
\tikzstyle{dashedlong2}=                  [dash pattern=on 18pt off 4pt]
% \tikzstyle{box4} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black,fill=orange!50]
% \tikzstyle{boxA} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1.3cm, text centered, draw=black,fill=pink!80]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [ultra thick,->,>={Latex[scale=1]},line width=2.5pt]
\tikzstyle{arrowdashed} = [thick, dashedlong2 ,->,>={Latex[scale=2]},line width=1pt]


\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=12em,thick]
%------------------------------------------------------------
% NODE SETUP
%------------------------------------------------------------
\node (CBL) [circleblank] {};
\node (C1) [circlelined, right of = CBL] {};
\node (C2) [circlelined, right of = C1] {};
\node (C3) [circlelined, right of = C2] {};
\node (C4) [circlelined, right of = C3] {};
\node (CBR) [circleblank, right of = C4] {};
\node (CB1) [circledashed, below of = C1] {};
\node (CB3) [circledashed, below of = C3] {};
\node (CA2) [circledashed, above of = C2] {};
\node (CA4) [circledashed, above of = C4] {};
\node[circleblank] (l2) at (30em,-8em) {\fontsize{20}{22.4}\selectfont$\ell_{\scriptscriptstyle 2}$};
\node[circleblank] (l1) at (54em,6em) {\fontsize{20}{22.4}\selectfont$\ell_{\scriptscriptstyle 1}$};
%------------------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------------------
% LINES
%------------------------------------------------------------
\draw[draw=black, thick] ([xshift=-24em]C1.center) -- (CBR.east);
\draw[draw=black, ultra thick] ([xshift=-24em, yshift=18em]C1.center) -- ([xshift=-24em, yshift=-18em]C1.center);
\draw[draw=black, dashedlong2, thick] (C2.center) -- ([xshift=12em, yshift=4em]CB1.center);
\draw[draw=black, dashedlong2, thick] (CA4.center) -- ([yshift=6em]l1.center);

%------------------------------------------------------------


%------------------------------------------------------------
% ARROWS FROM CIRCLES
%------------------------------------------------------------
\draw[arrow] (C1.center) -- node[anchor=north, xshift=-1em,yshift = -1em]{\fontsize{20}{22.4}\selectfont$u$}([xshift=3em]CBL.east);
\draw[arrow] (C2.center) -- node[anchor=north, xshift=1em,yshift = -1em]{\fontsize{20}{22.4}\selectfont$u$}([xshift=-3em]C3.west);
\draw[arrow] (C3.center) -- node[anchor=north, xshift=-1em,yshift = -1em]{\fontsize{20}{22.4}\selectfont$u$}([xshift=3em]C2.east);
\draw[arrow] (C4.center) -- node[anchor=north, xshift=1em,yshift = -1em]{\fontsize{20}{22.4}\selectfont$u$}([xshift=-3em]CBR.west);
%------------------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------------------
% ARROWS FROM DASHED CIRCLES
%------------------------------------------------------------
\draw[arrowdashed] (CB1.center) -- (C1.center);
\draw[arrowdashed] (CB3.center) -- (C3.center);
\draw[arrowdashed] (CA2.center) -- (C2.center);
\draw[arrowdashed] (CA4.center) -- (C4.center);
%------------------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------------------
% ARROWS FOR u,v,l
%------------------------------------------------------------
% First 'v' arrow
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=6em]C1.center) -- node[anchor=north, yshift=-3em]{\fontsize{20}{22.4}\selectfont$v$}([xshift=6em, yshift = 6em]CB1.center);
% Second 'v' arrow
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=6em]C2.center) -- node[anchor=south, yshift=3em]{\fontsize{20}{22.4}\selectfont$v$}([xshift=6em, yshift = -6em]CA2.center);
% Third 'v' arrow
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=6em]C1.center) -- node[anchor=north, yshift=-3em]{\fontsize{20}{22.4}\selectfont$v$}([xshift=6em, yshift = 6em]CB1.center);
% 'l_2' arrows
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=-2em]l2.center) --([xshift=12em, yshift=4em]CB1.center);
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=2em]l2.center) --([yshift=4em]CB3.center);

% 'l_1' arrows
\draw[arrow] ([yshift=2em]l1.center) --([yshift=6em]l1.center);
\draw[arrow] ([yshift=-2em]l1.center) --([yshift=-6em]l1.center);

%------------------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------------------
% Curved Arrows
%------------------------------------------------------------
\draw[arrow]
   (C1) ++(-0.75,0.25)  arc (135:65:1 and 2) -- ++(-45:13pt);
\draw[arrow]
   (C3) ++(-0.75,0.25)  arc (135:65:1 and 2) -- ++(-45:13pt);
\draw[arrow]
   (C2) ++(0.75,0.25)  arc (45:115:1 and 2) -- ++(-135:13pt);
%------------------------------------------------------------
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which turned out not so bad, however, making those **arrow heads on arcs** sit nicely was tedious and there probably is a much easier way to do it, one that looks better as well.

Is there an **alternative to arc**? Are the alternatives compatible with nodes? Anything than can make a curve would be good too as I currently have no ideas on how to even start drawing that half parabola curve thing yet either (and it's probably ridiculously easy to do).

Many Thanks
Ken

Comment: I believe you are looking for the library `bending`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I focus on the arcs here (and do not address the font sizes etc.). First of all, you may want to bend the arrow heads. This requires the `bending` library and to add `bend` to the arrow, e.g.

```
\tikzset{arrow/.style={ultra thick,->,>={Latex[scale=1,bend]},line width=2.5pt}}
```

(where I switched to `\tikzset` as `\tikzstyle` is deprecated). Then your arrows can be draw in a loop simply by saying

```
\foreach \X in {1,2,3} {\draw[arrow] (C\X) ++(170:0.75)  arc (170:10:0.75);}
```

Here I use polar coordinates. If you want these arrows longer or shorter, adjust the range of the polar angles `170` and `10`.

[image]

This is the MWE (where you could avoid some repetition by using more `\foreach` loops).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows.meta,bending}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{circlelined/.style={circle, minimum width=6em, text centered, draw=black, ultra thick},
circledashed/.style={dashedlong, circle, minimum width = 6em, text centered, draw=black, thick},
circleblank/.style={circle, minimum width=6em},
dashedlong/.style={dash pattern=on 22pt off 4pt},
dashedlong2/.style={dash pattern=on 18pt off 4pt},
arrow/.style={ultra thick,->,>={Latex[scale=1,bend]},line width=2.5pt},
arrowdashed/.style={thick, dashedlong2 ,->,>={Latex[scale=2,bend]},line width=1pt}}


\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=12em,thick]
%------------------------------------------------------------
% NODE SETUP
%------------------------------------------------------------
\node (CBL) [circleblank] {};
\node (C1) [circlelined, right of = CBL] {};
\node (C2) [circlelined, right of = C1] {};
\node (C3) [circlelined, right of = C2] {};
\node (C4) [circlelined, right of = C3] {};
\node (CBR) [circleblank, right of = C4] {};
\node (CB1) [circledashed, below of = C1] {};
\node (CB3) [circledashed, below of = C3] {};
\node (CA2) [circledashed, above of = C2] {};
\node (CA4) [circledashed, above of = C4] {};
\node[circleblank] (l2) at (30em,-8em) {\fontsize{20}{22.4}\selectfont$\ell_{\scriptscriptstyle 2}$};
\node[circleblank] (l1) at (54em,6em) {\fontsize{20}{22.4}\selectfont$\ell_{\scriptscriptstyle 1}$};
%------------------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------------------
% LINES
%------------------------------------------------------------
\draw[draw=black, thick] ([xshift=-24em]C1.center) -- (CBR.east);
\draw[draw=black, ultra thick] ([xshift=-24em, yshift=18em]C1.center) -- ([xshift=-24em, yshift=-18em]C1.center);
\draw[draw=black, dashedlong2, thick] (C2.center) -- ([xshift=12em, yshift=4em]CB1.center);
\draw[draw=black, dashedlong2, thick] (CA4.center) -- ([yshift=6em]l1.center);

%------------------------------------------------------------


%------------------------------------------------------------
% ARROWS FROM CIRCLES
%------------------------------------------------------------
\draw[arrow] (C1.center) -- node[anchor=north, xshift=-1em,yshift = -1em]{\fontsize{20}{22.4}\selectfont$u$}([xshift=3em]CBL.east);
\draw[arrow] (C2.center) -- node[anchor=north, xshift=1em,yshift = -1em]{\fontsize{20}{22.4}\selectfont$u$}([xshift=-3em]C3.west);
\draw[arrow] (C3.center) -- node[anchor=north, xshift=-1em,yshift = -1em]{\fontsize{20}{22.4}\selectfont$u$}([xshift=3em]C2.east);
\draw[arrow] (C4.center) -- node[anchor=north, xshift=1em,yshift = -1em]{\fontsize{20}{22.4}\selectfont$u$}([xshift=-3em]CBR.west);
%------------------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------------------
% ARROWS FROM DASHED CIRCLES
%------------------------------------------------------------
\draw[arrowdashed] (CB1.center) -- (C1.center);
\draw[arrowdashed] (CB3.center) -- (C3.center);
\draw[arrowdashed] (CA2.center) -- (C2.center);
\draw[arrowdashed] (CA4.center) -- (C4.center);
%------------------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------------------
% ARROWS FOR u,v,l
%------------------------------------------------------------
% First 'v' arrow
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=6em]C1.center) -- node[anchor=north, yshift=-3em]{\fontsize{20}{22.4}\selectfont$v$}([xshift=6em, yshift = 6em]CB1.center);
% Second 'v' arrow
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=6em]C2.center) -- node[anchor=south, yshift=3em]{\fontsize{20}{22.4}\selectfont$v$}([xshift=6em, yshift = -6em]CA2.center);
% Third 'v' arrow
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=6em]C1.center) -- node[anchor=north, yshift=-3em]{\fontsize{20}{22.4}\selectfont$v$}([xshift=6em, yshift = 6em]CB1.center);
% 'l_2' arrows
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=-2em]l2.center) --([xshift=12em, yshift=4em]CB1.center);
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=2em]l2.center) --([yshift=4em]CB3.center);

% 'l_1' arrows
\draw[arrow] ([yshift=2em]l1.center) --([yshift=6em]l1.center);
\draw[arrow] ([yshift=-2em]l1.center) --([yshift=-6em]l1.center);

%------------------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------------------
% Curved Arrows
%------------------------------------------------------------
\foreach \X in {1,2,3}
{\draw[arrow]
   (C\X) ++(170:0.75)  arc (170:10:0.75);}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was busy going through some bending examples after your comment. I completely agree that the bending on the arrow head itself is aesthetically pleasing. I have never used loops before, but seeing at it reduces the amount of typing out it's probably something I should think about in future.

Comment: Also, what was the issue with the font sizes ? Is it something I should look at changing?

Comment: @Ken I get complaints about the font sizes when I compile the above. However, these are warnings, and I do not know enough about fonts to judge whether or not this is something to worry about. (This was merely because there are a handful users on this site who have a bit interesting habits, so I wanted to say "yes, I saw these warnings, too." ;-)

Comment: Ahh, I had issues with the size of the letters attached to the nodes nd another page here on stackexchange recommended that fix. It works, so I didn't question it. However, thank you so much Marmot. I have a few other diagrams to draw up and I can see this bending coming in super handy.

Comment: +1 for the bending library, which I hadn't come across. I almost always learn nice tricks from your posts:)

Comment: @Andrew I am going through Marmot's posts now. Learning lots of neat things. :)