# Problem with arrowhead angling

Tags: tikz-arrows

In [Arrowhead angle in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/449008/arrowhead-angle-in-tikz) a solution for the bad angling of arrowheads is given using the `bending` library.

My problem: in the "keyhole circuit" drawing

[image: Keyhole circuit]

produced with the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,bending}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[decoration={markings,mark=at position 1.2cm with {\arrow[line width=1pt]{stealth}},mark=at position 8cm with {\arrow[line width=1pt]{stealth}},mark=at position 18.7cm with {\arrow[line width=1pt]{stealth}},mark=at position 20.65cm with {\arrow[line width=1pt]{stealth[flex=1]}}}]
\path[draw,line width=0.8pt,postaction=decorate] (10:0.5) -- +(2,0) arc (2:358:2.5) -- +(-2,0) arc (-9.5:-350.5:0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

the `flex=1` is ignored. Why? *Where* the `flex=...` is required? I've tried several positions. Almost all give errors.

Comment: In order to use `flex` with an effect you need to use `arrows.meta` and then `Stealth[flex=1]`. You do not load `arrows.meta` so the option does not even get parsed. The answer you are referring to is unfortunately not too accurate either.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, I've added `arrows.meta` and changed `[flex=1]` to `Stealth[flex=1]`. The effect is a greater arrowhead and no angling correction. Do you want the new code and drawing?

Comment: The reason is that when you use `decorations.markings` in the usual way, the only thing that is known at the point you draw the arrow is the tangent and nothing beyond. In particular, the curvature is set to zero. So you need to make the arrow aware of the shape of the curve around this location, which is what the answer below does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load `arrows.meta` to make use of `flex`, and then the correct syntax is `Stealth[flex]` rather than `stealth[flex]`. However, I would bend the arrows along the paths.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,bending,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430239
    arc arrow/.style args={%
    to pos #1 with length #2}{
    decoration={
        markings,
         mark=at position 0 with {\pgfextra{%
         \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmpArrowTime}{#2/(\pgfdecoratedpathlength)}
         \xdef\tmpArrowTime{\tmpArrowTime}}},
        mark=at position {#1-\tmpArrowTime} with {\coordinate(@1);},
        mark=at position {#1-2*\tmpArrowTime/3} with {\coordinate(@2);},
        mark=at position {#1-\tmpArrowTime/3} with {\coordinate(@3);},
        mark=at position {#1} with {\coordinate(@4);
        \draw[-{Stealth[length=#2,bend]}]       
        (@1) .. controls (@2) and (@3) .. (@4);},
        },
     postaction=decorate,
     },starc arrow/.style={arc arrow=to pos #1 with length 3.14mm}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[draw,line width=0.8pt,postaction=decorate,starc arrow/.list={0.06,0.33,0.86,0.94}] (10:0.5) -- +(2,0) arc (2:358:2.5) -- +(-2,0) arc (-9.5:-350.5:0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]